# How to create session in Rails 4 using Authlogic and HTTP post request (test)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, http-post, authlogic

I am somewhat new to Rails 4 and am working on a project that requires authentication. I have recently implemented Authlogic to handle it.

The problem is a specific test for the session controller where I try to log in using HTTP post, which fails redirecting me to the login path. I am interested in this because it will probably be used later to log an Android application using the users in my Rails app.

This is the test:

```
sessions_controller_test.rb
   test "should post create" do
     this_user = users(:one)
     post :create, username: this_user.username, password: 'secret'
     assert_redirected_to admin_url
     assert_equal this_user.id, current_user.id #session[:user_id]
   end
```

This is the code being tested:

```
sessions_controller.rb       
   def create
    @user_session = Session.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
     flash[:notice] = "Login successful."
     redirect_to admin_url
    else
     redirect_to login_url, alert: "Invalid user/password combination"
    end
   end
```

And the test result:

```
  2) Failure:
SessionsControllerTest#test_should_post_create [/home/mario/railsprj/depot/test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb:13]:
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/admin> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/login>.
Expected "http://test.host/admin" to be === "http://test.host/login".
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue. Check `@user_session.errors` in the else branch of your session_controller#create. Or switch to `@user_session.save!` temporarily to throw an error if validation is wrong. In my case a validation related to user.confirmed_at was failing.

The other thing to check is that your test has `setup :activate_authlogic` which is required before you can Session.create.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it is not too late for the answer. The problem in your code is that you are missing the params.

You have to change the test:

```
  test "should post create" do
     this_user = users(:one)
     post :create, user_session: { username: this_user.username, password: 
'secret'}
```

Or you have to change the controller:

```
sessions_controller.rb       
   def create
    @user_session = Session.new(username: params[:username], password: params[:password])
```

Only one of both choices. I think is better the first solution, but is a kind of taste.

Regards

Roberto